# line detection using hough transform

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge, hough-transform

I am working on c# project ,i am using aforge for  line detection of particular color in a bmp image by using hough transform.When i am processing the image i get pixel format not supported exception .my images are 24bpprgb and the docs clearly tells the format supported.trying to convert it to the supported formats always ends up in the above exception.Can anyone enlighten me on this...
or can anyone tell me the necessary steps to convert the bmp 's to any of the supported formats using hough transform for line detection

Answer (score 0):

In your case the image must be grayscale (8-bpp).
You can convert it using AForge Grayscale filter and then apply the Hough transform.

You can also take a look at:
https://github.com/dajuric/accord-net-extensions

The library implements generic image (Image) and it is easily convertible to AForge image.
Also it wrapps algorithms (primary for Accord.NET tough - for now).